# Как сделать псевдоэлемент :after перманентным после нажатия?

Tags: html, css

Я изучаю html и css всего один день, поэтому моих знаний явно не хватает, чтобы уверенно использовать синтаксис. В скриншоте показано как должно получиться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 250px 10px 250px;
    
    
}
.menu__list {
    position: relative;
    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__list:after {
    content: " ";
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    
    background: #985e5b;;
    transition: .0s linear;
    top: 28px;
}

.menu__list:active:after {
    display: block;

}

.menu__list:active {
      color: #985e5b;
}
```

```html
    <div class="list">
        <a class="menu__list">breakfast</a>
        <a class="menu__list">lunch</a>
        <a class="menu__list">drinks</a>
        <a class="menu__list">desserts</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли ::after задать свойство background.
И так же можете использывать ::hover

Если хотите оставлять акстивный класс, тогда нужно использывать JS

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  links('.menu__list')
})


const links = selector => {
  const linksItems = document.querySelectorAll(selector)

  linksItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      linksItems.forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'))
      item.classList.add('active')
    })
  })

}
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 250px 10px 250px;
}

.menu__list {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__list.active {
  color: #985e5b;
}

.menu__list.active:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #985e5b;
  transition: .0s linear;
  top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <a class="menu__list">breakfast</a>
  <a class="menu__list">lunch</a>
  <a class="menu__list">drinks</a>
  <a class="menu__list">desserts</a>
</div>
```

Comment: изпользовать :hover нет никакого смысла, ведь мне нужно, чтобы цвет выбранной категории и полоска под ней осталась там после нажатия.

Comment: псевдоклас active, .будет работать только во время нажатия,  тут нужен JS

Comment: а можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию была выделена первая категория (breakfast), но при нажатии на другую оставалась выделена только вторая?

Comment: да, добавьте класс 'active'  ссылке в HTML

Answer (score 2):

С использованием **jquery** добавляешь класс при нажатии.

```js
$('.list .menu__list').click(function() {
$('.list .menu__list').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 250px 10px 250px;
}

.menu__list {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__list:after {
  content: " ";
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #985e5b;
  transition: .0s linear;
  top: 28px;
}

.menu__list.active {
  color: #985e5b;
}

.menu__list:hover {
  color: #985e5b;
}

.menu__list:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.menu__list.active:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <a class="menu__list">breakfast</a>
  <a class="menu__list">lunch</a>
  <a class="menu__list">drinks</a>
  <a class="menu__list">desserts</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

добавить `class="active"` и с помощью js отслеживать нажатие и добавлять нужному элементу этот класс, а у другого убирать его